# How to show images when hovered a single list element of ngfor ulist in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

```js
showfavstar(val)
    {
      this.favstar = true;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="listboxtickets">
    <li class="selectlistticket" *ngFor="let fav of favlist" (mouseover)="showfavstar(fav.req_id)" (mouseleave)="hidefavstar()">
  <div class="atickname" (click)="timetracker(fav.req_id,fav.ticket_summary,fav.time_logged*60*1000)"> {{fav.ticket_summary.substring(0,20)}} </div>
      <div> {{fav.time_logged} </div>
      <div class="atickstat" [hidden]="!favstar"> <img class="staraimg" src="assets/images/star_icon.png" (click)="removefav(fav.req_id)"/> </div>
      <div class="namelinet"> <img src="assets/images/text_bottomline.png"/> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to show star image for only hovered list?Now i get all the star images

Comment: where is yout .ts functions ? please post full code

Comment: this function shows all the images of a list.But i need only selectively hovered single list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be achived using single variable which you took here i.e favstar.

Try your code like this

```
<ul class="listboxtickets">
    <li class="selectlistticket" *ngFor="let fav of favlist" (mouseover)="showfavstar(fav)" (mouseleave)="hidefavstar(fav)">
        <div class="atickname" (click)="timetracker(fav.req_id,fav.ticket_summary,fav.time_logged*60*1000)"> 
            {{fav.ticket_summary.substring(0,20)}} 
        </div>
        <div> {{fav.time_logged} </div>
        <div class="atickstat" [hidden]="!fav?.Show">
            <img class="staraimg" src="assets/images/star_icon.png" (click)="removefav(fav.req_id)"/> 
         </div>
        <div class="namelinet"> <img src="assets/images/text_bottomline.png"/> </div>
    </li>
</ul>

showfavstar(fav){
    fav.Show = true;

    for(let i = 0; i < this.favlist.length; i++){
        this.favlist[i].Show = false;
    }
}
hidefavstar(val){
    fav.Show = true;

    for(let i = 0; i < this.favlist.length; i++){
        this.favlist[i].Show = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry..i don't have enough reputations to increase useful answer. I'm very new to this one

Comment: And i want to know how to get value of selected in dropdown option after using ngfor?I was using (change)= value(fav.id). But i'm not getting the value of selected option

Comment: its okii :) please ask new question if this is your new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711332/how-to-use-electron-browser-window-inside-components-in-angular-cli

Comment: can u please help me?

Comment: sorry i have no idea about electron